# Problems with file uploading

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, upload

On my react form, I have a couple of files uploaded to be sent to the backend. This is the code sample for the form submit button:

```
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setDisabled(true);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("areaOrcamentaria", areaOrcamentaria);
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("files", files[i]);
        }
        for (var value of formData.values()) {
            console.log(value);
        }

        axios
            .post("http://localhost:5001/nfe/upload", formData)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
```

And, logging that formData, what I get is:

[image: Teste 1]

"teste1" is my "areaOrcamentaria", the 2 uploaded files and some axios data (i guess).

However, when posting to the backend, with these code samples:

```
    app.use("/nfe", nfeRoutes);
```

This is on my server's index.js, it routes to nfeRoutes to:

```
import express from "express";
import { postNfe } from "../controllers/nfe.js";

const router = express.Router();


// NFE
router.post("/upload", postNfe)

export default router;

And this is my postNfe: 

    export const postNfe = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("postNfe");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({ message: "NFE received" });
};
```

The files are shown to be on formdata at the front-end, they apprear on the request payload but the server show them as {}. I don't need to store them, just convert them (XML) to json. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like multer to help you handle image uploads as this makes this much easier and will allow you to have a middleware for uploading them. Example below

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var port = 3000;

var app = express()

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

/*
app.use('/a',express.static('/b'));
Above line would serve all files/folders inside of the 'b' directory
And make them accessible through http://localhost:3000/a.
*/
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

app.post('/profile-upload-single', upload.single('profile-file'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `profile-file` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.file))
  var response = '<a href="/">Home</a><br>'
  response += "Files uploaded successfully.<br>"
  response += `<img src="${req.file.path}" /><br>`
  return res.send(response)
})

app.post('/profile-upload-multiple', upload.array('profile-files', 12), function (req, res, next) {
    // req.files is array of `profile-files` files
    // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
    var response = '<a href="/">Home</a><br>'
    response += "Files uploaded successfully.<br>"
    for(var i=0;i<req.files.length;i++){
        response += `<img src="${req.files[i].path}" /><br>`
    }
    
    return res.send(response)
})
   

app.listen(port,() => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}!`))
```

You can also configure this with things like S3 to do image uploading as well

Comment: I'll only have .xml files from the user, and I won't store those .xml files. I just need them temporarily to convert them to JSON and only then store them on the DB. The real problem seems to access those files as they get to the backend.